# media query retina display

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this css code that shows a div on retina displays.

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (orientation:landscape){#warning-message,#wrapper{display:block;}}
```

The problem is that I don't want it to be shown on Mac but just on iPhones and iPads. How can I be more target specific?

Answer (score 0):

Access the your developer tools in the browser(I use Chrome for this, press F12) and determine the screen sizes you'd like to modify(Chrome has them in the top left). For example, if you look up a macbook with an 11 in. screen it's only 1366 x 768, but your largest ipad will be 768 x 1024. You can make specific media constraints per device by using "and" with your CSS tags. Otherwise, [take a look at this link for more specific detail on the CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries), you may have a "not '...' and is Retina" option.

```
@media not all and (monochrome) { ... }
@media (min-width: 700px) and (orientation: landscape) { ... }
```

Good Luck on your project!